What is an efficient way to store items in a way where they can be indexed by a string and a number?
I've been contemplating this problem for a while now, and I've come up empty handed on solutions for it. I'm trying to use C++ for it because it's the language I know the most about and am the most comfortable with.
I want to be able to use two key types to be able to sort and search through a set of data. The two key types in question do not have to be of the same variety, but in practice will almost always be, and is what I'm aiming for.
For simplicity, let's say I have a large amount of items, and they each have a name and an ID I have given them, and I want to store them in a large building. These items can be in multiple locations and not just one, but they each have a std::string for a name, and a unsigned int for an ID.
I want to be able to store these items in a way that minimizes extra memory usage and such that I can search through the data in a search time that isn't linear.
The first thing to come to mind is to use a std::map or std::unordered_map. The idea would be to have two separate maps, one for names and one for IDs, and have the elements point to eachother. Then a separate third map that would have the actual locations, with the IDs as the key.
So something like:
std::map<std::string, std::uint32_t*> namesToIDs;
std::map<std::uint32_t, std::string*> IDsToNames;

std::map<std::uint32_t, std::string> items;

const std::string& getLocation(const std::string& name);

const std::string& getLocation(std::uint32_t id);

The main problem with this is that if one of the name or ID maps reallocated, the other would be pointing to invalid locations and I wouldn't have any way of knowing when this would happen.
There have been other ideas that I've had but they've fallen flat.
Is there any superior way to organize this data in a way that has a light-ish touch on RAM and can be searched through in a REASONABLE time complexity?

boost has a library for this. Not sure if it meets your requirements but you should probably have a look at it.

Why not have two maps like this: std::map<std::uint32_t, std::shared_ptr<Item>> idToItemMap and std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Item>> nameToItemMap?

Perhaps you want a database library rather than any particular C++ data structure.

"if one of the name or ID maps reallocated" - std::map won't ever reallocate. Nor will std::unordered_map for that matter, it guarantees pointer stability. (At significant cost to its efficiency.)

The description is unclear, what means "can be in multiple locations". Are lifetimes of these data objects managed by different places all over the program? If so then you might want to use likes of boost::intrusive::set as indexes. Those do not manage life times. That would make joining and leaving the indexes responsibility of objects.

If one is the "main" key, you could have a "main" map std::map<std::uint32_t, Item> containing all items by ID and one (or even more) additional map(s) std::map<std::string, std::uint32_t> mapping names (or other properties) to IDs. The latter could also be a std::multimap in case names are not unique. It's an additional indirection, but especially with int keys that's pretty cheap. And it's hard to find a good solution without additional indirection in one or another way.

Search the internet for "C++ index tables database".  Implement the main table, then create std::map<key, table-index> for each different key type.

You can basically reproduce what databases do: store the entities and the indexes to entities separately.
class Entity {};
using EntityIdentifier = unsigned;
using EntityName = std::string;
class EntityDatabase
{
    std::vector<Entity> _entities;
    std::map<EntityIdentifier, std::size_t> _id_index;
    std::map<EntityName, std::size_t> _name_index;

public:
    Entity&
    operator[](EntityIdentifier id)
    { return _entities[_id_index[id]]; }

    Entity const&
    operator[](EntityIdentifier id) const
    { return _entities[_id_index[id]]; }

    Entity&
    operator[](EntityName const& name)
    { return _entities[_name_index[name]]; }

    Entity const&
    operator[](EntityName const& name) const
    { return _entities[_name_index[name]; }

    // add methods to add data into _entities
};


This is what I would do also, with the caveat that deleting entries gets complicated: You have to remove the object from _entities, and then you have to do a full run through both of the maps - both to remove the object to delete, but also to -1 all the values that point to after the index you just removed.
